# PHP writing into excel

Tags: php, xls, iis-8.5

I have migrated my application from Apache to IIS. I am exporting data from database to csv and xls file.
After migration csv is generated properly but xls is giving following error:

> The file you are trying to open, [filename], is in a different format than specified by the file extension" error opening Excel files

I found in many blogs that there might be some MIME issue. The following header is provided:

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; name=".$date."_".$heure.".xls");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$date."_".$heure.".xls");
```

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: What format are you using for the Excel file that you're generating? BIFF of OfficeOpenXML? (Please don't say you're using html markup)

Comment: Sorry for late reply.....
 @Suyog i am creating xls using "class.writeexcel_biffwriter.inc.php" file.

Comment: Also it is exporting the HTML code in xls file.